# how to call AuthenticateExternalAsync from startup.cs

Tags: identityserver3

I get claims from client A using WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.  I have to use these claims and authenticate against an inhouse idp and redirect the user to a different portal.  I am thinking of using AuthenticateExternalAsync in my startup.cs to pass the external identity from Client A to inhouse idp.  However, my idp is not selfhosted so how do I get the user servcie exposed to call  AuthenticateExternalAsync? Please advise if this is right approach? Thanks.